# Tableau Web diff Creator vs Explorere

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Can some one list out functionality difference between creator Vs Explorer on Tableau Web for Tableau 2021.3 or 2022.1 versions.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.tableau.com/pricing/teams-orgs.

Also, [release navigator](https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/tableau.core.product.marketing/viz/ReleaseNavigator-V21/FeaturesInVersionDash) will show you the different features by version.